# How to get data from a control into another ASP.net page?

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a time sheet for work to learn more about asp and making database connections I am also using this time to prepare for my next C# and database design class which start on Wednesday. I'd like to know how I can get data from default.aspx and display it in timesheetdisplay.aspx, and I would also like to know how I can make it so the person doesn't have to enter the full id "100000111" as it appears in the database just the last 3.

```
<asp:TextBox id="xBadgeTextBox" runat="server" width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're redirecting from page to page, consider using the `Server.Transfer("timesheetdisplay.aspx", true)` method when navigating away from your default.aspx page. Note the second parameter, true, which will persist all ViewState and QueryString data across from page to page.

Answer (score 1):

As far as passing data between pages you can pass it via QueryString, Session variables, or by persisting it to some sort of data store such as a Database.  In the situation above I would look at passing via Querystring parameter.  Be sure that if you do do this that you validate the data on the new page to ensure its safety and validity before using it (think SQL Injection Attack).

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

As far as your second question goes I would say that this could be handled on the server side if you are sure that the last 3 digits will always be unique.  Or were you looking to prompt the user entering data similar to Google?  If so look at the AutoComplete Extender in the AJAX Control Toolkit or look at doing something similar in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a unique key, store the value you are transfering in the users session, redirect the user and include the key in the query string, grab the key, and then get the value.  Something like this:

```
    //---On Default---
    var value = "can be a single string or even a complext object...";

    var keyName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Session[keyName] = value;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("timesheetdisplay.aspx?SID=" + keyName);


    //---On TimeSheet---
    var getKeyName = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["sid"].ToString();
    var myValue = HttpContext.Current.Session[keyName];
```

To get the id from a partial ID I would do it just like Muhammad Akhtar said:

```
select * From yourtable where id  like '%111'
```